# List the title of all books in the same category as books previously purchased by customers 2010, 2011, 2012, without before bought books by them

Tags: sql

In oracle SQL, I tried this to get the output for 2010 just to check and it works but could not get the answer for all at once

```
SELECT title FROM books WHERE category IN (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM b_books
            JOIN orderitems USING ( isbn )
            JOIN orders USING ( order# )
        WHERE customer# = 2010) AND isbn NOT IN (SELECT isbn
        FROM orders
            JOIN orderitems USING ( order# ) WHERE customer# = 2010 );
```

But I tried a lot of ways to get for 2010,2011,2012 at once using 'AND', 'comma' and other ways but could not get the output. So please can you help me?

Comment: Please read [ask].  Show all table ddl, sample data, expected output. "other ways but could not get the output" does not help the reader.  Show what is failing.  you probably want... customer# in ( 1018,1019,1020)

Comment: My apology for not asking a clear question. However, the suggestion that you have given worked for me to get the expected output. Thank you so much, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and there are some adjustments that I did:

```
SELECT title 
FROM books 
WHERE category IN (SELECT DISTINCT category 
                   FROM books
                   JOIN orderitems USING (isbn)
                   JOIN orders USING (order#)
                   WHERE customer# = 2010) 
AND isbn NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT isbn
                 FROM books
                 JOIN orderitems USING (isbn)
                 JOIN orders USING (order#)
                 WHERE customer# = 2010);
```